# Apache write permissions ( Drupal module unable to write/create css/js files)

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using a Drupal module called 'Code Per Node'.  It allows basically what the name describes: custom code in the form of JS or CSS on a per node basis.  Upon publishing the node, the module writes the css and js to a file specified in the module's configuration settings.

In development, I have the directory set to `/cpn`, I've temporarily made the permissions for that folder `0777` just to cover all angles.

The problem is, I've moved the site to a staging server and something about the environment is restricting the module from writing the CSS and JS files. it returns a 'The file could not be created' error upon publishing.

I've tried: Setting open permissions and moving directory inside of `/sites/default`, no dice.

Is there anything else I should look at that would prevent this module from writing these files? Perhaps an Apache config setting?

As a side note, I would much prefer the custom code be generated inline on the page, so if anyone knows any actively supported modules that accomplish this, that would also be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Check admin/reports/status page  
2. Set write permission for the apache user (probably, www-data on debian-like systems)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the tmp directory for Drupal was still set to a local path.